# Validate a date from the <input type="date"....>

Tags: javascript, php, validation, date

I would like to validate the field for the input type of date. Currently, I am trying to use the javascript method to validate the field(s).

This is the code that I have used.

```
var RE_DOB = /^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;
```

My current date format is 29/07/2014

Just wondering on how I can validate the fields for the input type of date. I am able to achieve them on text, but it would be good if the input type is date as the user may be using the website on a mobile device, where it would show a datepicker on these devices.

Comment: Shouldn't a HTML5 compliant browser already provide the client side validation? Or are you talking about server-side validation in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, the value of a date input is [ISO-8601 standard](http://xkcd.com/1179/): `YYYY-MM-DD`

Externally, however, the date input will use whatever format has been defined by the user's computer (locale-aware), making it easy for people to use.

Your validation should be looking for `^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d$` (although that alone is, of course, insufficient for date validation, unless `9876-54-32` is a valid date to you!)

Answer (score 0):

You can still enter everything into a `type="date"` input field. The only thing the `type="date"` attribute does is to display a date picker (e.x. on most mobile devices). There isn't a browser validation already implemented.

What you need is:

1. Server side validation (PHP)
2. Optional client side validation (JS)

They depend on what format you like to accept. As mentioned already you can use JavaScripts `match()` string function to validate the input on the client site. For example

```
if(yourInput.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/) == false)
    alert('invalid date');
```

To validate against a `YYYY-MM-DD` pattern on client side.

On server side you should use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) or [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/datetime.construct.php) and check the [`DateTime::getLastErrors()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/datetime.getlasterrors.php) for parsing errors which will tell you that the input of the user isn't a valid date.